# How to fix virtualbox unknown filesystem type 'vbox'

Tags: linux, virtualbox, archlinux

I want to make a virtual machine for web development on archlinux guest that acts like vagrant box. I don't want to use vagrant box because I want to learn how to do things on my own first and I want to keep the disk space used by the machine at minimum as possible. For this I have installed and configured apache2, php, mariadb with a total of 640M used on disk. I have forwarded guest 80 port to host 127.0.0.1:8080.

I encounter an error with the vboxfs module, I have installed virtualbox-guest-module as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Install_the_Guest_Additions) and after a machine reboot tried:
`mount -t vboxfs share_name mount_location` and I get this error `unknown filesystem type 'vbox'`.

I have searched google and all the results make reference to the `virtualbox-guest-utils` from archlinux but the problem is I don't need all the dependencies that package has (alsa, xorg, video driver etc.) and I don't know witch deps I need or I don't need from that package... so I wander if it is possible and it is enough to use just the vboxfs module to be able to use the share functionality from Virtualbox.

Comment: See: [**VirtualBox - Archwiki**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox)  Always check the Archlinux Wiki first. They are well done and usually provide all the information necessary.

Comment: I think you didn't read what I wrote... did you saw my link? How do you think it got there? I'm not trying to be a douche bag but please say if you have something to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made a typo. It should be `vboxsf` instead of `vboxfs`. I did the same and was wondering why it doesn't work. So the full command is:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf share_name mount_location
```

To remember the correct type you can think of it as the abbreviation of VirtualBox Shared Folder.